# Azure Storage Queue queueServiceClient.GetQueues

Tags: c#, azure

I have many queues in my azure storage account and using c# code I am generating Metric log, right now i am passing each queue name to access it but i am trying to replace that with iteration of all queues in storage one by one. Have anyone used queueServiceClient.GetQueues? I would appreciate if you can provide c# code on how to iterate all queues one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    var storage_connection_str = "";
    var queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(storage_connection_str);
    var queues = queueServiceClient.GetQueues();

    foreach (var queue in queues) {
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Name);
        QueueClient qc = new QueueClient(storage_connection_str, queue.Name);
        // do your things here...
    }
```

Result:
[image]

[image]